# Wiring smokes in series: one smoke beeps a lot

Tags: electrical, smoke-detectors

We wired three smokes. However, every so often (but always in the middle of the night) one of them starts beeping. I suspect that it is not actually being powered by electricity, but off the battery.

I wired them so that smoke A goes to a junction box. Then from the junction box to smoke B and from the junction box to smoke C. (All via attic access) Does this mean that they are not really in series and therefore explains why smoke B misbehaves?

(Or perhaps my wires are just loose and I need to check the wiring in the box, which I am going to do right now).
Thx, Catherine

Comment: a "smoke" is either a cigarette or a byproduct of combustion ... what did you actually wire

Answer (score 1):

A loose/disconnected neutral will cause a hardwired smoke alarm to go off.

Comment: FYI, "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content."

Comment: None of the neutrals are loose

Answer (score 1):

Try new batteries.

If it didn't beep at you when the battery is low and it's being powered by line voltage, you wouldn't know until the power was out, which would be a bad time to find out if your house was also on fire.